# jQuery append order

Tags: jquery, append

For all the simplicity I  just cant see why this does not work.

I need to append a div to the body of the document, then a copy of the same div again but hidden, then another div, then a copy of the other same div again but hidden, and so on...

```
    $.each(myObj.items, function(i, item) {

        // createItem simply finds an html fragment in the document,
        // clones it and returns it
        var $i = createItem(item);

        // add a div first that clears floats - this is needed before every item
        $('body').append('<div class="clear"/>');

        // append a clone of the html fragment
        $('body').append($i.clone());

        // add another div that clears floats
        $('body').append('<div class="clear"/>');

        // append a clone of the html fragment but hide it
        $('body').append($i.clone().addClass('hidden'));

    });
```

I am expecting:

```
    <body>
        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item">item</div>

        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item hidden">item</div>

        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item">item</div>

        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item hidden">item</div>
        ...
    </body>
```

but i get..

```
    <body>
        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item">item</div>

        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item">item</div>

        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item hidden">item</div>

        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item">item</div>

        <div class="clear"/>
        <div class="item hidden">item</div>
        ...
    </body>
```

Why does the first skip?

**Edit**

My source html is like this:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="template hidden">..</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I clone the template div, return it to my function, add a div (class='clear'), then a clone of the returned div, then another div (class='clear') then another clone of the returned div

There are no more than 5 items in my list.

**Edit 2**

Stupid User Error... the code works fine. I didn't realise that the first line I had was hard coded not auto generated.

Sorry guys... (feel stupid)

Comment: can you provide a (non)working example?  This seems to work like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/hpw95/

Comment: that is the frustrating part. I can't see why it wouldnt work and you have confirmed that it does but for some strange reason (excuse the developer mantra) it doesnt work on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you cloning an existing set of divs? I.e. you already have one on your page, so your function clones and adds a regular one and *then* adds another clone as hidden.

Comment: I have hidden div which i clone, then remove the hidden class and return to my function. I attach this to the document but because I want to attach a copy of it directly beneath i clone it again.

Comment: Well than you just answered yourself! remove it.

Comment: I is stupid. Sorry everyone. I just saw that one was hard coded and the others are all generated. My apologies again... Should RTFM....

Comment: @Alan - I saw a great phrase for that on twitter the other day: "Can't brain today. I have the dumb." Happens to us all :)

Comment: @Alan - Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me (http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/M5PQ8/), when called with three items.

Are you sure you didn't put the extra divs in the body yourself?  How many items are in your `myObj.items` ?